# Hinges for a Murphy Desk

Tags: doors, woodworking, cabinets, hinges

I am building a murphy desk (that closes up, not down). The desk would basically extend an Ikea Kallax-like custom cube shelf unit. I would like the table surface to seamlessly continue the bottom shelf and I can do it with the hinges pictured below. The bottom left part of the image shows how the table will be in the up or closed position, and the bottom right displays the table is open or down (notice the clean joined finished). However, these hinges will **on be the table surface**. So, my question is: are there any hinges out there that can be **on the outside (or below the table surface)** instead of the inside / top and provide the same positions for two wood pieces as these inside hinges?

In case you are wondering, the table will also have legs in the front and these hinges aren't bearing the full load.

[image: possible hinges]

Comment: A [bi-fold corner hinge](https://www.google.com/search?q=bi-fold+corner+hinge) maybe? You'd usually find them on the inside of a corner kitchen cabinet.

Comment: research `embedded hinges`

Comment: Is this desk intended to be in front of, on the side of, or on the top of, the Kallax (which come in several configurations)?

Comment: It's not a Kallax, it's a Kallax-like cubicle shelving built with plywood. The shelving unit is attached to the wall with the bottom about 30" above the floor, the table is at the front of the unit, and it is folded down (with attached legs that fold out to support the other end of the table).